# A recursive function to print each new position to console?

Tags: c++, recursion

this is a c++ homework question so I would very much appreciate some guidance in the right direction. 
The problem asks for input of a positive integer to represent position. If the initial position is even, the new position is d/2, and if odd the new position is 3*d+1, and this continues until position is one.

Ex: Enter a positive integer: 11

The OJP for 11: 11 34 17 52 26 13 40 20 10 5 16 8 4 2 1

This is some code that I got to work by iteration:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int ollyjumppattern(int d)
{
    if (d == 1)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    else if (d % 2 == 0)
    {
        return (d / 2);
    }
    else
    {
        return (3 * d + 1);
    }
}


int main()
{
    int target;
    cout << "Enter a positive integer: ";
    cin >> target;
    cout << "The OJP for " << target << ": ";

    if (target == 1)
    {
        cout << "1";
    }
    else
    {
        cout << target;
        while (target != 1)
        {
            cout << " " << ollyjumppattern(target) << " ";
            target = ollyjumppattern(target);
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

And this is what I have so far for recursive:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int ollyjumppattern(int d)
{
    if (d == 1)
    {
        cout << "1";
        return 1;
    }
    else if (d % 2 == 0)
    {
        int result = ollyjumppattern(d/2);
        cout << result << " ";
        return result;
    }
    else
    {
        int result = ollyjumppattern(3*d+1);
        cout << result << " ";
        return result;
    }
}


int main()
{
    int target;
    cout << "Enter a positive integer: ";
    cin >> target;
    cout << "The OJP for " << target << ": ";

    if (target == 1)
    {
        cout << "1";
    }
    else
    {
        cout << ollyjumppattern(target);
        cout << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This code crashes when I try to run it
I would very much appreciate any tips

Comment: Could you give the error

Comment: Step through the program with a debugger.

Comment: Shouldn't you be printing `d`, not `result`?

Comment: When I try your program with input `11` I get `The OJP for 11: 11 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1` and no crash.

Comment: Tips?  hailstones and magic-numbers.

Comment: Solving this with a recursive solution in C++ is such overkill.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your recursion is fine, the only problem in your code is that you're printing the wrong thing. You should be printing `d`, not `result`, because after all the recursion is done, all the results will just be `1`.

You also don't need to test for `target == 1` in `main()`, because this will be handled by the function itself.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void ollyjumppattern(int d)
{
    cout << d << ' ';
    if (d == 1)
    {
        return;
    }
    else if (d % 2 == 0)
    {
        ollyjumppattern(d/2);
    }
    else
    {
        ollyjumppattern(3*d+1);
    }
}


int main()
{
    int target;
    cout << "Enter a positive integer: ";
    cin >> target;
    cout << "The OJP for " << target << ": ";

    ollyjumppattern(target);
    cout << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```